# dplyr filter returning 0 results when selecting a number from numerical variable

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, numeric

My data contains a numerical variable (containing numerous significant digits) and I want to select only the values of 6. I assume there is a problem when using the == function and the number significant digits but neither solution is working.

I have tried both 6 and 6.000000 (which was copied out of the data frame).

```
`df %>% filter(SCL == 6)`
```

Also returns 0 values

```
`df %>% filter(SCL >= 6 & SCL <= 6)`
```

Returns the correct values but also includes ones I do not want

```
`df %>% filter(SCL > 5.99 & SCL < 6.01)`
```

Comment: This is likely a classic floating point issue - see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: Is there a way to 100% confirm you are selecting only the 6.000000 instead of 5.999999 or 6.0000001. I am afraid if I use a rounding function I might lose accuracy of my data. Because the data are created by averaging I only want exactly 6

Comment: The answers in the link provide several approaches to address this in R, take a look and if they dont answer your question, edit it to explain exactly why those approaches failed. Good luck!

Comment: Compare `library(dplyr); df <- data.frame(row = 1:2, SCL = c(6.00000000000000, 6.00000000000001)); df %>% filter(SCL == 6); df %>% filter(SCL %>% near(6))`. Floating point numbers cannot perfectly represent all numbers, so in any language that uses them, we have to specify (or it's specified for us) some threshold for "close enough."

Comment: Thank you @jpsmith and Jon Spring, it turns out that none of my values are exactly 6, What I would call 6 is actually "6.00000047700000038731", so I will have to do some sort of rounding.

Comment: Good news that both round(SCL,6) & filter(SCL = "6.00000047700000038731"). Return the same results. I was able to determine this by exploring my data  using: sprintf("%.20f",df$SCL)

Comment: @RichardJohansen yes that is a likely a result of the floating point issue described in the link above. Consider using `all.equal()`, `near()`, `sprintf()`, etc.